# unable to access array objects

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am trying to access into an array from computed. console vuex showed computed array is there, but I cannot access into the array from created(). Any help is appreciated!

I have tried to save into a data array, does not find the computed array.

```
<template>
    <div>
        {{ product.product_name }}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'product_4',
    created() {
        this.product = this.products.find((product) => product.id == 4);
    },
    data() {
        return {
            product: {}
        }
    },
    computed: {
        products() {
            return this.$store.getters.products;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

store.js

```
state: {
    products:[]
},
getters: {
    products(state) {
        return state.products;
    }
},
mutations: {
    updateGetProducts(state, payload) {
        state.products = payload;
    }
},
actions: {
    getProducts(context) {
        axios.get('/api/getproducts')
            .then((response)=> {
                context.commit('updateGetProducts', response.data);
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try to console `products`? and are you sure that there's a property called `product_name`?

Comment: yes it is displayed in vuex but under computed() products

Comment: please reproduce your code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue) in order to debug, you could use an array of sample products instead of axios call

Comment: it is working in the vue codesandbox, the only difference is the axios call. https://codesandbox.io/s/1v8ov5jr47

Comment: I also tried to replace the axios with the same array, same problem: the computed has the array but the data is undefined.

Comment: Where do you call `getProducts` action?

Comment: i called from app.vue. its frustrating as i redid the replication on sandbox and it works. the only other difference is that i am using laravel as backend api, but this should not affect vue state manipulation

Comment: did some more tests and i realise when i get a non array, the data can be assigned. But when i change to an array, it cannot be assigned to data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the computed to this:

```
computed: {
    product() {
        return this.$store.getters.products.find((product) => product.id == 4);
    }
}
```

I can access directly this way, do not need to put into data as it is not advised to do so in vue documentation.

Answer (score 0):

`computed` properties are mounted after the `created` life cycle hook, so try to use another hook like mounted :

```
 mounted(){
      this.product = this.products.find((product) => product.id == 4);
    }
```

Comment: what went wrong with my answer since there's someone comes to downvote it

Comment: the result is still the same, data return product as undefined. Not sure who down voted you thou.

Comment: please share your store object

Answer (score 0):

I think should not make any problem, if you use like below, but you have to ensure that find method returning a single object instead of null or array of objects.

```
 created() {
            this.product = this.$store.getters.products.find((product) => product.id == 4);
        }
```

but I ll prefer to use that into mounted hook like below when you want to use computed property.

```
mounted() {
        this.product = this.products.find((product) => product.id == 4);
    }
```

And after looking your updated code you can use below solution, because I have seen that you have used actions to update products using api, so below solution will solve your problem

```
<template>
    <div>
        {{ product.product_name }}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'product_4',
    data() {
        return {

        }
    },
    computed: {
        product() {
            return this.$store.getters.products.find((p) => p.id == 4);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: tried your first method and the mounted, result is the same: undefined

Comment: see the  content of this.$store.getters.products , is it undefined or not?

Comment: in the html template i did a <div v-for="product in products">{{ product.product_name }}</div> it shows all the products. but i need to get a specific product out.

Comment: on the computed it has the array from my store.js, but on created() or mounted() is it undefined

Comment: then simply check your find method whether it is returning anything or not. this.products.find((product) => product.id == 4)

Comment: it is empty or undefined

Comment: ok, you should ensure that there is product with id 4, and you can try to use filter method. this.products.filter((product) => product.id == 4)

Comment: yes it has product_name, i have 4 objects in the array:
as displayed from vuex:
computed
products: Array[4]
 0: Object
    product_name: 'product 4',
    id: 4
 1: Object
 2: Object
 3: Object